# Creating a loop in R to find a minimum value of a vector by using comparison operators (>, <, ==, etc.)

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, comparison-operators

I have a vector that contains 100 random values between 0 and 100 called "aVector". I need to create a loop that finds the minimum value within aVector using "if" statements and comparison operators (>, <, ==, etc.). I can't use min() or max() functions in or outside of the loop.

What I have so far (aVector is setup but my loop doesn't work):

```
set.seed

aVector <- sample(0:100, 100, replace=FALSE)

for (i in 1:(aVector)) {
  if(aVector[i] < 1)
    1 = aVector[i]
}
```

Comment: You don't care about `1`, you care about the low, which you'll have to initialize before the loop, e.g. `low <- Inf; for (n in aVector) ...`

Comment: Unrelated, but you need to pass `set.seed` a number, e.g. `set.seed(1970)`

Comment: After I initialize the low, how would I write that into the loop? (very new to R)

Comment: The same way, just update it in the loop: `low <- some_new_low`

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. I want to use comparison operators to pull the value out of the vector within my loop assuming I don't know the low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. First create a variable called "low" with a high value (as @alistaire suggested). Then, loop through your values of aVector. At each value, check if the value is less than low. If it is, update low to that value.

```
set.seed(42)

aVector <- sample(0:100, 100, replace=FALSE)

low <- Inf # initialize with high value
for (i in aVector) {

  if(i < low){
    low <- i
  }

}
print(low)

# Confirm we got correct answer
min(aVector)
```

Answer (score -2):

I like that code.  Let me use it to write a function if you don't mind @Rob Marty:

[image]

```
Minx <- function(x){
    Min <- Inf
    for(i in x){
        if(i<Min){
            Min <- i
            }
         }
    Min
    }
```

I wrote the function to be able to mimic R's inbuilt function `min()`.  Just learning...

Comment: (1) I'm not sure that enclosing the solution within a function really adds anything useful to the existing answer. (2) Please post code in textual, **code format** (i.e. a code block) - images are inaccessible (can't be searched, bad for visually impaired people using screen readers, etc etc etc).

Comment: I want to be able to reuse the code for more general things: Sort vectors, find percentiles, etc. It is just to learn how to program in R without using inbuilt functions.